# Iframe display issues on iOS iPhones

Tags: ios, css, iphone, iframe

I am experiencing a weird issue with iframes displayng on some phones and not displaying on some phones. 
(Displays on all androids)
(Does not work on iphone 6,7 but works on 7 plus and the 7S and a few other iphones)

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
 <iframe src='http://app.brandyourcar.com/signup/index/form-main-display-group-thingy' style='border: 0;' width='100%' height='770px' scrolling='no'></iframe>
</div>enter code here
```

I have tried a lot of the solutions on Stack and none seem to work for me.

few examples :1.) `<div id="scroller" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
<iframe height="100%" id="iframe" scrolling="no" width="100%" id="iframe" src="url" />
</div>`
2.) `<div id="scroller" style="height: 400px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
<iframe height="100%" id="iframe" scrolling="no" width="100%" id="iframe" src="data/testdocument.pdf" />
</div>`

and many other Java script solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the latest versions of safari have a new security feature called "prevent cross site tracking" enabled by default that doesn't allow the third party cookies. The user can disable this, but I'm trying to find a workaround to avoid the user intervention. For now, you can detect if the third party cookies are allowed and if not you can display an alert message saying how to disable this feature.

I hope it helps.